# how to fix "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_binary' "?

Tags: mercurial

i compiled mercurial successfully as follows:
...

```
copying build/scripts-2.7/hg -> /usr/local/bin
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/hg to 755
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial-2.8.1-py2.7.egg-info
as3:~/mercurial-2.8.1# cd ~
as3:~# hg clone http://hg.cat-v.org/werc/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/hg", line 25, in <module>
mercurial.util.set_binary(fp)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 103, in __getattribute__
return getattr(self._module, attr)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_binary'
as3:~#
```

how to fix it?tks.
my python version:2.7.6

Answer (score 5):

Note that you have installed mercurial from sources into `/usr/local/bin`, but the error message mentions `/usr/bin/hg`. It means you have a different version of mercurial main script installed under `/usr/bin/hg`, which then tries to use new mercurial library from `/usr/local`. The error occurs, because the 2 are incompatible.

To fix this, remove older mercurial from `/usr/bin`. You may need to call `rehash` in your shell as well, for it to pick it up, depending on the shell.

If mercurial does not work then, it means `/usr/local/bin` is not in your PATH. If that is the case you'll need to fix the PATH, or just symlink new hg, like so:

```
# ln -s /usr/local/bin/hg /usr/bin
```

But that will require root access, for example, calling it through sudo.

Comment: Awesome. Although instead of a comment, we usually confirm that something worked by accepting an answer. But it's most important, that now you're fine.

Comment: thanks, I did link in opposite way from bin to usr/local and it's work